# Tar Error: implausibly old time stamp 1970-01-01 00:00:00

Tags: filesystem, encryption, home-directory, tar

My home directory is encrypted and I want to remove the encryption. I have performed the following actions and the problem occurs at step 4:

1. Backed up (encrypted) home folder to `/var/backup` using `sbackup` utility
2. Deleted home folder: `$ rm -rf /home/michael`
3. Removed packages: `$ apt-get remove ecryptfs-utils libecryptfs0`
4. **Boot Natty Narwhal to root shell and restore home directory**

When attempting extract the backup tarball, the following error is returned:

`$ sudo tar xf files.tar`

```
tar: home/.ecryptfs/michael/.Private/ECRYPTFS_FNEK_ENCRYPTED.FWZdI4ZeDbIPc-QG6GsHgtjGSc5ns3EFhATgHkOpWaANk8HckMCC2VA1Ak--/ECRYPTFS_FNEK_ENCRYPTED.FWZdI4ZeDbIPc-QG6GsHgtjGSc5ns3EFhATg1ab7dVYDmjv48RAB0zaKb---/ECRYPTFS_FNEK_ENCRYPTED.FWZdI4ZeDbIPc-QG6GsHgtjGSc5ns3EFhATgJ3T3MqBAxoNpmnpplaft5U--/ECRYPTFS_FNEK_ENCRYPTED.FWZdI4ZeDbIPc-QG6GsHgtjGSc5ns3EFhATg2Go7nLmgf-x2EH31fsA9UU--/ECRYPTFS_FNEK_ENCRYPTED.FWZdI4ZeDbIPc-QG6GsHgtjGSc5ns3EFhATgv.heQDWdQZf9WXV2gJKTSE--/ECRYPTFS_FNEK_ENCRYPTED.FWZdI4ZeDbIPc-QG6GsHgtjGSc5ns3EFhATg775dUZ66CvwfX9jvQ55LpE--: implausibly old time stamp 1970-01-01 00:00:00
```

This isn't what I had in mind. How can I resolve this problem?

Thank you.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I see 1 flaw in your strategy:

You use `sbackup` to create a backup and `tar` to restore it. That does not make sense to me. Either you create and restore with `tar` or you create with `sbackup` and restore with `srestore`.

There is a GUI for restoring your files that you made with sbackup. If you need command line (due to removing /home)

`sudo srestore.py {backupfile} /home/$USER`

(this will restore from {backupfile} the files from /home/$USER to /home/$USER; if you want it somewhere else you can add a 2nd directory as adestination).

This might also solve your date problem: srestore probably uses tar but another (older) version of tar that you have installed.

Comment: Thanks for your help. With hindsight, I will use sbackup/srestore next time.